# why I get two different instances of the same service?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have ExerciseService that has **public x property**:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ExerciseService extends CrudService<IExercise> {
  public x:number = 0;
  exercisesByGroups: IGroupExercises[] = [];
  constructor() {
    super(ResourseApi.exercise, Resourse.exercise);
  }
}
```

in the ExerciseContainerComponent I modify it in the constructor:

```
this.exerciseService.x = 4;
```

When I inject ExerciseService in the TrainingContainerComponent and console.log x I get 0 instead of 4.

Why this happends? does it mean I created two instances of ExerciseService ? How to prevent that?

Comment: can you provide TS file for `ExerciseContainerComponent` ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msnasf?file=src/app/app.component.ts I just pasted here the file, so that you can see line 42

Comment: Your Stackblitz gives an error: `Error in src/main.ts
HostResourceResolver: could not resolve ./exercise-container.component.html in context of /~/src/app/app.component.ts)`

Comment: @HDJEMAI I told you I just pasted the code so you could see, this is not supposed to compile..
By the way I am using lazt loading, maybe this is related ?